# adding 802.11n to a network

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, 802.11n

My setup:

- LinkSys 310n (dd-wrt)

  several G devices (iphone, xbox, etc)

  some N devices (mbp, mac mini, etc)

I'd like to add a dedicated N (or g - lock the 310n to g) channel to the network.  Any thoughts?  Is buying a second cheap G router the best option (setting up a wired bridge with dd-wrt), get an N bridge (if so, any recommendations?)

The only reason I actually care about N at all is getting some speed to my mac mini (HTPC).  I really don't want/need a new router (unless there's not a good option that costs less than a 610n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a G access point and put it on the same range the N is on.  Then restrict your current router's wireless to only allow N clients. You can get used AP's on ebay dirt cheap.

Comment: Yah, I get that.  I'd like to not setup a new subnet though.  dd-wrt on both sides with a cabled bridge would work, just looking for something that's less work.